# EF Core 5 failing while trying to update a foreign key which is also part of a unique Index

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Like the title says, I am trying to update a foreign key and getting below error:

> The property 'Student.APID' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

The `Student` class looks like this:

```
 public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        EntityCodes = new HashSet<EntityCode>();
        StudentAPHists = new HashSet<StudentAPHist>();
    }

    public string DepartmentJurName { get; set; }
    public decimal StudentMBA { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dtLastVerified { get; set; }
    public string LastVerifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dtCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StudentVerificationExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public int APID { get; set; }
    public int? DTPID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentPayee StudentPayee { get; set; }
    public virtual DelqStudentPayee DelqStudentPayee { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityCode> EntityCodes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentAPHist> StudentAPHists { get; set; }
}
```

The `StudentPayee` looks like this:

```
public partial class StudentPayee
{
    public StudentPayee()
    {
        StudentPayeeUpdateHists = new HashSet<StudentPayeeUpdateHist>();
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public decimal StudentMBA { get; set; }
    public decimal PayeeCode { get; set; }
    public string TaxIDMask { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public int APID { get; set; }
    public decimal UserRecipient { get; set; }
    public decimal PmtRecipient { get; set; }
    public DateTime dtCreate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Payee Payee { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipient PmtRecipientNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Recipient UserRecipientNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentPayeeUpdateHist> StudentPayeeUpdateHists { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And the `OnModelCreating` method looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Student", "dbo");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.APID, e.StudentMBA }, "UNQ_APID_StudentMBA")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Comments)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentJurName)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.StudentMBA).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastVerifiedBy)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);               

            entity.Property(e => e.StudentVerificationExpiryDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.dtCreated).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.dtLastVerified).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.StudentPayee)
                .WithMany(p => p.Students)
                .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.APID)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.APID)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_APID_StudentPayee");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.DelqStudentPayee)
                .WithMany(p => p.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DTPID)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Student_Delqpayee");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Department)
                .WithMany(p => p.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StudentMBA)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Student_Student");
        });
```

Entity config for `StudentPayee`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<StudentPayee>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.StudentMBA, e.PayeeCode })
                .HasName("PK_StudentIDMask");

            entity.ToTable("StudentPayee", "dbo");

            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.PayeeCode, e.StudentMBA }, "NonClusteredIndex-20201218-155947")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.APID, "UNQ_APID")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.StudentMBA).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PayeeCode).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.APID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.Active)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdatedBy)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.PmtRecipient).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserRecipient).HasColumnType("decimal(10, 0)");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaxIDMask)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.dtCreate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Student)
                .WithMany(p => p.StudentPayees)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StudentMBA)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_StudentPayee_Student");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Payee)
                .WithMany(p => p.StudentPayees)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PayeeCode)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_StudentPayee_Payee");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.PmtRecipientNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.StudentPayeePmtRecipientNavigations)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PmtRecipient)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_StudentPayee_PmtRecipient");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.UserRecipientNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.StudentPayeeTBRRecipientNavigations)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TBRRecipient)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_StudentPayee_TBRRecipient");
        });
```

As you can see the `APID` is a foreign key and part of the unique index. So, whenever I try to update the `APID` like below, I get the error. This used to work with Entity Framework 6.

```
Student _student = DataBase.Students
                           .Single(x => x.Student ID == studentId);

if (_student != null)
{
    _student.APID = p_APID;

    DataBase.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You can make APID unique, but you certailnly don' t need to make it a part of key.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "part of key"? Are you referring to foreign key? It is setup as a foreign key in database.

Comment: I mean the error "Student.APID' is part of a key  ..."

Comment: This was generated by Reverse engineering tool, EF core power tool and I am not sure that's part of the problem. I am only getting issue when updating the APID.

Comment: Do you have a `modelBuilder.Entity<StudentPayee>`? The above only has the entity configuration for `Student`.

Comment: @ajawad987 Updated with `StudentPayee` entity config.

Comment: Some properties used in fluent configiration are missing - `Student.StudentPayee`, `Student.StudentPayees`, `StudentPayee.Student` and `StudentPayee.StudentMBA`. Not sure if they are relevant, but since they seem to define two circular relationships between these entities, it's good to be provided. Also if you skipped something from fluent configuration related to these two entities. Because I don't see the unique **key** mentioned in the error message (unique key is not the same as unique index).

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated the post and added a few configs that I ignored earlier. I am not sure how they were relevant but if you think it will help you get better idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still cannot create a model for these two entities (after commenting out all references to all other not included here), because of error "The relationship from 'StudentPayee.Student' to 'Student.StudentPayees' with foreign key properties {'StudentMBA' : decimal} cannot target the primary key {'StudentID' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query)` to update the foreign key instead of LINQ. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this snippet in your EF configuration:

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.StudentPayee)
    .WithMany(p => p.Students)
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.APID)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.APID)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_APID_StudentPayee");
```

Your defining a "PrincipalKey" as part of this relationship, making `APID` the primary key of your `Student` table. To verify this is actually happening, in your database IDE (I'm assuming SQL Server), which field does it show as the primary key?

Remove the `.HasPrincipalKey` part, and add the following as well:

```
entity.HasKey(s => s.StudentID);
```

Comment: I removed the `.HasPrincipalKey` and added the `entity.HasKey(s => s.StudentID);`. Now I am getting different error at the start of my app. `The relationship from 'Student.StudentPayee' to 'StudentPayee.Students' with foreign key properties {'APID: int'} cannot target primary key because its not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.`

Comment: Can you update your question to show the entity configuration of the `StudentPayee` as well? I suspect that is missing a primary key.

Comment: Updated the question with the `StudentPayee` model. The entity config for `StudentPayee` doesn't have anything related to Student but it does have unique index `entity.HasIndex(e => e.APID, "UNQ_APID").IsUnique();`